# Service and Fragment doesn't access same SharedPreferences in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, sharedpreferences

I have a GPS service and Settings Fragment. When Service called first time or stopped and started again by user because settings may changed I want to access values at the shared Preferences which was written by Settings Fragment.

Code at Service:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        setLOCATION_INTERVAL(sharedPreferences.getInt("KEY_GPS_FREQ", 1) * 1000);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Interval Value from SharedPref " + LOCATION_INTERVAL, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here, I also tried getBaseContext(). But both of them only returns 1000 this means it doesn't read correct value.

And at the Settings Fragment side here is my code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putInt("KEY_GPS_FREQ", seekBar.getProgress());
                editor.apply();
```

I also tried :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

at service side  and at fragment side:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

they did not work too.

Comment: Use PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) on both sides to access the application-level default preferences and not the Activity default preferences.

Comment: @BladeCoder you are man of the day, it worked, you saved my PC`s life :D Thank's a lot